# Dockerize react-native dev environment & connect Android device to WSL2

Tags: windows, docker, react-native, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to dockerize my react native development environment. Currently I have windows on my laptop, and I don't have the option to change that. I also have WSL2 installed  and I started to build my dockerfile from this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/reactnativecommunity/react-native-android)

I also want to use my device, so I have to somehow connect the container (the docker runs actually in WSL2)  with my android device. The WSL2 don't support USB devices (that are connected to the host windows system) currently so I was thinking about setting up a wireless adb connection on the local network but since my android is <11 I have to do some initial setup which requires me to connect adb over USB which is due to the reasons above, not possible... I don't want to use an USB server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the whole dev-environment setup and working on linux/wsl, you can use socat to relay requests from wsl2 to adb on windows. You may have to deal with some firewall issues, but this works for me:

On Windows:

1. Run `adb -a -P 5037 nodaemon server` (credit to [this redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/g9k968/ubuntu_2004_adb_support/fph1zwx?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))
2. In another terminal, run `adb devices` to ensure your device is properly connected over usb.

On linux/wsl2:

3. Run `socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:5037,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f 2):5037` (credit to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#enable-access-to-adb-server-from-wsl2))

If you are developing for android with react-native and need to launch the metro bundler, you will need to open a port for the metro bundler on your windows firewall. I will assume you are using port 8081.

Run as administrator in powershell (Windows):

4. `$WSL_CLIENT = bash.exe -c "ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'"`
5. `iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8081 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=8081 connectaddress=$WSL_CLIENT"`

You should now be able to deploy your project to andriod.

On linux/wsl2:

6. `npx react-native start`
7. `npx react-native run-android`

If this doesn't work, the credited sources for steps (1) and (3) provide similar methods for achieving this. If you make a docker image, please share it here!